# datepicker field authorizing specific characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jqueryUI and its datePicker which works fine, but in France date is more likely written with slashes (DD/MM/YYYY) than it is with dashes (DD-MM-YYYY) but datePicker doesn't allow user to input slashes.

I would like datePicker fields to allow users to input slashes in addition to other authorized characters (that is to say **both** dashes **and** slashes  but I don't know where to change that. The format has already been changed to the french one.

Any hints ?

My function so far that initialise any field that need a date picker (which is mostly here just to translate most of the text to french) :

```
function initDatePicker(){
    $('*[class*=datepicker]:visible').each(function() {
        $( this ).datepicker({
            altField: "#datepicker",
            closeText: 'Fermer',
            prevText: 'Précédent',
            nextText: 'Suivant',
            firstDay:1,
            currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
            monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
            dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
            weekHeader: 'Sem.',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery ui Datepicker can't accept both format at the same time.
You could use two inputs text like :

```
<input id="datepicker" pattern="\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{4}" type="text" />
<input id="hiddenField" type="text" style="display:none;" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#hiddenField').datepicker({
          [...]
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          onSelect:function(date){
               $('#datepicker').val(date);
          }
     });
     $('#datepicker').on("click", function() {
          $('#hiddenField').datepicker("show");
     });
</script>
```

This should work, please edit it if needed to improve it

Comment: But I want both options to be allowed

Comment: It works well, thank you, a bit more hackish but that will do ;)